# News bar not work its need to move/work all time

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

That Not Work its need to move/work all time. this id need to be bar news
That Not Work its need to move/work all time. this id need to be bar news

```
   protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        Task.Run(() => NewsInLabel());

    }

    public void NewsInLabel()
    {
        string text = "עולם המגזינים הטובים, מגזיני גיימינג מעולים, עולם המגזינים הטובים, מגזיני גיימינג מעולים";
        StringBuilder someString = new StringBuilder("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
        int i = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            for (int i1 = 0; i1 < 20; i1++)
            {
                if (i1 + i < text.Length)
                {
                    someString[i1] = text[i1 + i];
                }
                else i = 0;
            }
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            la.Text = someString.ToString();
            i++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: I want to make the label effect move to right, and I want it to work as while as MAIN PAGE is the only page in the stack

Comment: do you want the character moves to the right  like some scroll ad ?check below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could check this,is it the effect you need:

```
public partial class MaqueText : ContentPage
{
    private bool Execute { get; set; }
    public MaqueText ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
        Label1.Text = "This is to simulate a really long sentence for testing purposes";
        Label1.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start;
        Label1.VerticalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;
        Label1.LineBreakMode = LineBreakMode.NoWrap;
    }
    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        Execute = true;

        Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50), () =>
        {
            Label1.TranslationX += 5f;

            if (Math.Abs(Label1.TranslationX) > Width)
            {
                Label1.TranslationX = 0;
            }

            return Execute;
        });
    }
    protected override void OnDisappearing()
    {
        base.OnDisappearing();

        Execute = false;
    }
}
```